# looking for the equivalent c code of asm

Tags: c, assembly

I want to know the corresponding c code of the following asm code, and if you can a explanation of the asm code

```
PUBLIC fonction2
_tab   DW  0aH DUP (?)
_idx$ = 8               ; size =4
_value$ = 12             ; size =2
fonction2 PROC
         push ebp
         mov ebp, esp

         mov eax, DWORD PTR _idx$[ebp]
         mov cx, WORD PTR _value$[ebp]
         mov word PTR _tab[eax*2], cx

         pop ebp
         ret 0
fonction2 ENDP
```

What's `_idx$` and `_value$`.
Thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 7):

```
void fonction2 (int idx, short value)
{
   tab [idx] = value;
}
```

Comment: thanks for ur answer ;).the params does finish with $? i dont understand idx$[ebp] and _value$[ebp]

Comment: it's `[ebp + 8]`, `[ebp + 12]`, respectively

Comment: Why are we using  _tab[eax*2] i don't understand the 2, btw here is a good articles explaining the stack frame stuff http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2011/02/04/where-the-top-of-the-stack-is-on-x86/#id7